# Web.config customisations lost using a Wix installer to perform an upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I've created a WiX installer to deploy a set of websites on at a customer site and use xmlfile to plug correct values for hostnames and connectionStrings into our web.config files.  Since these values come from the installer UI I've run into a problem when doing an Upgrade install using:

```
msiexec /i Websites.msi  /l*vx Website.log REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus
```

While the update performs correctly the xmlfile actions plug empty values in since the UI isn't run.

Is there a way of getting these values into the installer without parsing the XML or prompting the installation engineer for the values again?

Cheers,
Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [Remember Property](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern) pattern only adapted for XML instead of Regisry.  WiX doesn't have an XML peek pattern yet so you'll have to write a custom action.

Another gotcha to watch out for is since you are modifying the XML future upgrades won't install newer versions of the XML by default since it now has user data.

Comment: This might not work well with IIS/ASP.NET ( nothing new there sadly ) but if you split your XML into 2 XML's the install will be a lot easier. Basically one file that the user doesn't modify that the installer can safely replace over and over and another XML file that the user/application/installer does modify that has your variation points in it.   Basically think  stock.xml and override/transform.xml.

Comment: This is basically what I did.  I was hoping to never have to write a custom action, but couldn't get around it.  

I put together a (pretty dirty) C# dll to read in the values I needed from any current web.config and web.constants.config files and store them as the existing WiX variables.

Not ideal, and I have to keep an eye on what the dev team do but it's enough to be getting on with.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like your web.config to be modified during install only, you can condition your components containing XmlFile elements with `Not Installed` condition. In this case the action to modify the XML file won't run for those components during upgrade.

Comment: Unfortunately we're going to need both the web.config to be updated and the original values that would have been given to the installer passed plugged back in to the connectionStrings.

I'm getting a bad feeling that I'll have to either write some sort of connection string parser as a custom action or force an update to pop up the configuration screen somehow.